# Angelscript wrong type conversion

Tags: c, types, double, precision, angelscript

I'm currently trying to use angelscript with a simple code,  following the official website's examples.

But when i try to initialise a double variable like below in my script :

```
double x=1/2;
```

the variable x appears to be initialised with the value 0.

It only works when i write
   double x=1/2.0; or double x=1.0/2;

Does it exist a way to make angelscript work in double precision when i type double x=1/2 without adding any more code in the script ?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Using some macro chicanery:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DIV * 1.0 / 

int main(void)
{
    double x = 1 DIV 2;

    printf("%f\n", x);
    return 0;
}
```

`DIV` can also be defined as:

```
#define DIV / (double)
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `1` and `2` are integers, and:

```
int x = 1/2;
```

Would be 0.  If `x` is actually a double, you get an *implicit cast conversion*:

```
double x = (double)(1/2);
```

Which means `1/2 = 0` becomes `0.0`. Notice that is not the same as:

```
double x = (double)1/2;
```

Which will do what you want.

Numbers with decimals are doubles, and dividing an int by a double produces a double.  You can also do this with casting each number:

```
double x = (double)1/(double)2;
```

Which is handy if `1` and `2` are actually int variables -- by casting this way, their value will be converted to a double before the division, so the product will be a double.

Answer (score 0):

When you divide an `int` by an `int`, the result is an `int`. The quotient is the result, the remainder is discarded. Here, `1 / 2` yields a quotient of zero and a remainder of 1. If you need a `double`, try `1.0 / 2`.

No, there is no way to get a `double`  by dividing two `int`s without casting the result.